# How to set multiple buttons according to JSON response?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an app in which I am fetching data from server. So, I have used JSON parsing in my code. I am successfully parsed my JSON from server. Now I want to set buttons in layout according to their visibility getting from JSON response.

That is if visibility true then button should visible and if false button should disable. It works but if some button has visibility false then there is a space in layout. So how to set in layout dynamically that all visible buttons show in line.

I have created three linear layouts each contains three buttons.Now if json response says visibility false for some button I set visibility to off for that button.

```
  if (Menuname.equals("StudentDailyDiary")) {
                                studentdiary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

moreOptionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                hrview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                rlleftview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                rlrightview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            if (Menuname.equals("BookSearch")) {
                                studlibrary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

moreOptionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                hrview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                rlleftview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                rlrightview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
```

Say in first layout three buttons are there from which second button has visibility false then on position of second button third button should be placed there should be no blank space for buttons in all layout.That is if third button has visibility false then first button of second layout should set on position of third button.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use **`RecyclerView`**

Comment: You have to used RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager for this kind of situation.

Comment: @MayurPatel Yes, thank you it works.

Comment: @Kinjal You welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the correct ViewGroup to use is the `GridLayout`.

Here a simple example:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val numbers = arrayOf("BUTTON1", "BUTTON2", "BUTTON4", "BUTTON5", "BUTTON6")

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers)

        gridView.adapter = adapter

        gridView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
            parent, v, position, id ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, (v as TextView).text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses String but you can make an Adapter of whatever you want. Now after you JSON response just fill your array and set it to the adapter.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank You. It helps me and solve my problem. I have taken recyclerview with gridlayout in java.

Answer (score 0):

there are three options for elements visibility,

```
View.VISIBLE
View.INVISIBLE 
View.GONE
```

use View.GONE for elements that you don't want to show.

Answer (score 0):

the different between

```
View.INVISIBLE
```

and

```
View.GONE
```

is that View.GONE take no space and you should use view.GONE

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to do this

**1:-**

```
View.VISIBLE  //Visible the view which is acquire its space
View.INVISIBLE //Invisible the view and it acquire the space 
View.GONE //visibility Gone of its view and also not acquire view space
```

**2:-**

you can use `RecyclerView` and pass the model to `adapter` and then show buttons according to its `model`.

Answer (score 0):

Set your buttons **Visibility** to **Gone** in your layout XML
So they don't left any blank space while their Visibility are INVISIBLE

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```